# Prevent auto-correction for one cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a mission critical workbook that does a bunch of lookups based on a user typed input in on cell. The user input gets erroneously *corrected* if the user types something that looks like a typo to the auto-correct. For example, when the user types "cna" the auto-correct changes it to "can", which is usually a good thing, but a bad thing in this case. We want to look up "cna". The simple solution is to turn off auto-correct, but we want/like auto-correct, just not in this one user input cell.

**How do I keep auto-correct on for the application/workbook, but prevent auto-correct for the user input cell (one cell) in question?**

I researched it a bit and couldn't find a way to turn auto-correct off for one cell. It seems to be a global setting.

I looked and didn't find an event that occurs prior to the auto-correct so I could capture the "cna", let auto-correct *correct* the value to "can", turn off events, then change it back to "cna". For example, the value is already "can" when this event is triggered:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   debug.print target.value '<- returns "can" already
End Sub
```

I don't want to add "cna" to the list of acceptable auto-correct words, because I want "cna" to be corrected to "can" in all cells but the user input cell in question.

Comment: Add a worksheet_OnSelect sub that turns off auto-correct if the desired target cell is selected and on for all other cells

Comment: That worked! Thanks! If you create an answer I'll give you cred. Otherwise I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some further error checking you can do so you may prefer the following function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceText = IIf(Target = Me.Range("input_cell"), False, True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flephal's comment, this is how I solved it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input sheet").Range("input_cell").Address Then
         Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceText = False
    Else
        Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceText = True
    End If
End Sub
```